# how to show selected date of first date picker in the second date picker in swift

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, datepicker

I am using two `datePickers` in my code, I want to show selected date of first `datePicker` in the second when we click on second `datePicker`. For this purpose I am using pod of `DatePickerDialog`. I have tried every method i got no way how to set first selected date as the start date of second `datePicker`. I am using `pod DatePickerDialog` for this. Please tell me solution according to this.
i am using this pod 
https://github.com/squimer/DatePickerDialog-iOS-Swift

Please see my code :

```
if textField == self.leaveField {
        ShowDropDown()
        textField.endEditing(true)
    }else if textField == self.fromDateField {
        DatePickerDialog().show("Select Date", doneButtonTitle: "Done", cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", datePickerMode: .date) {
                (date) -> Void in
            if let dt = date {
                //UserDefaults.standard.set(dt, forKey: "startDate")
                let formatter = DateFormatter()
                formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
                self.fromDateField.text = formatter.string(from: dt)

            }
            textField.endEditing(true)
        }

    }else if textField == self.toDateField {
        //let updatedDate = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "startDate")
        DatePickerDialog().show("Select Date", doneButtonTitle: "Done", cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", datePickerMode: .date) {
                (date) -> Void in
            if let dt = date {
                let formatter = DateFormatter()
                formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
                self.toDateField.text = formatter.string(from: dt)

                let start = self.fromDateField.text
                let end = self.toDateField.text
                let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

                let startDate:NSDate = dateFormatter.date(from: start!) as! NSDate
                let endDate:NSDate = dateFormatter.date(from: end!) as! NSDate

                let components = Date.daysBetween(start: startDate as Date, end: endDate as Date)
                //let components = cal.components(unit, fromDate: startDate, toDate: endDate, options: nil)
                //let components = cal.components(unit, fromDate: startDate, toDate: endDate, options: nil)


                self.totalDaysLbl.text = "Total Days " + "\(components)"
                let char: Character = "-"
                let string = self.totalDaysLbl.text
                let result = string?.range(of: "\(char)")
                if let result1 = result{
                    let otherAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry!", message: "You cannot set the date in negative.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

                    let dismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)

                    otherAlert.addAction(dismiss)

                    self.present(otherAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    self.totalDaysLbl.text = ""
                }
            }
        }
        textField.endEditing(true)
    }
```

Comment: try minimum and maximum date properties of picker

Comment: hi bro...
i am using pod for date. it has not these properties..
please tell me solution according to this

Comment: post the reference for Pod library you are using

Comment: i am using this
https://github.com/squimer/DatePickerDialog-iOS-Swift

Answer (score 1):

You should always read the API documentation before using it. There are parameters you can pass in the `show` method to achieve this. You can first convert the first `textField` string to `date` as below,

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let selectedDate = formatter.date(from: self.fromDateField.text!)
```

And then use the below method to pass this `date` as `defaultDate`,

```
open func show(_ title: String,
    doneButtonTitle: String = "Done",
    cancelButtonTitle: String = "Cancel",
    defaultDate: Date = Date(),
    minimumDate: Date? = nil, 
    maximumDate: Date? = nil,
    datePickerMode: UIDatePickerMode = .dateAndTime,
    callback: @escaping DatePickerCallback) {
```

Comment: if you selectedDate at minimumDate you can't select date behind from date

Comment: @Vinodh Yes, i think OP should pass selected date as `defaultDate` and `minimumDate` so that user can not select `ToDate` less than the `fromDate`.

Answer (score 0):

When you select date from first date picker then store it in variable.

Then use-

```
SeconddatePicker.date = //selectedDate
```

It will set tge deafult date for your second date picker.